# Некорректное обновление полей пользователя Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

User Entity состоит из следующих полей:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "id_group")
    private int groupId;

    @Column(name = "journal_number")
    private int journalNumber;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;
}
```

При попытке обновить поля firstName и lastName перестает авторизоваться под измененным пользователем. Причем никакие другие данные в таблице не изменяются.
Пароль шифруется bCryptEncoder.

Представление:

```
<form th:action="@{/admin/user}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{password}"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{groupId}"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{active}"/>
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{username}"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">Имя</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="Имя" name="firstName" th:field="*{firstName}" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Фамилия</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Фамилия" name="lastName" th:field="*{lastName}" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="journalNumber" class="sr-only">Номер в журнале</label>
        <input type="text" id="journalNumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Номер в журнале" name="journalNumber" th:field="*{journalNumber}" required>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Изменить</button>
</form>
```

Контроллер:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/admin/user")
    public String addUpdateUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
        userService.updateUser(user);

        return "redirect:/admin/user";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/admin/user/edit")
    public ModelAndView getUserForEdit(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelAndView mav) {
        User user = userService.getUserByName(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

        mav.addObject("user", userService.getUserById(id));
        mav.addObject("userListForEdit", userService.getListUserByGroupId(user.getGroupId()));
        mav.addObject("flag", true);

        mav.setViewName("admin");
        return mav;
    }
```

Сервис:

```
@Override
public void updateUser(User user) {
    userDao.saveAndFlush(user);
}
```

Повторюсь, данные в БД лежат точно такие же. Метод логина от спринга, не кастомный. Но в конечном итоге присылает обратно Invalid user or password.

В чем может быть проблема, не совсем понимаю, может кто сталкивался с таким?

**UPD:
WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/images/**",
                    "/js/**", "/registration").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()

            .and()
            .logout().deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

            .and()
            .rememberMe().key("secret").tokenValiditySeconds(86400)

            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
}

protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, active from user where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select u.username, ur.roles from user u inner join user_role ur on u.id = ur.user_id where u.username=?");
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

UPD: Log Spring Security

```
21:25:06.271 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.p.JdbcUserDetailsManager#211 User '2222' has no authorities and will be treated as 'not found'
21:25:06.427 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.a.d.DaoAuthenticationProvider#148 User '2222' not found
21:25:06.431 [http-nio-8080-exec-7] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#345 Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

Comment: Приложите security config. Неясно какие у вас настройки и какой способ аутентификации.

Comment: @aleshka-batman , обновил

Comment: Как вариант : проверьте, что юзер действительно поменялся в базе, а так же посмотрите логи spring security. Обратите внимание на то, как оно пытается аутентифицировать измененного юзера и по какой причине не может.

Comment: @aleshka-batman , в базе смотрю, меняется имя и фамилия, все остальные поля остаются неизменны. Как вариант, копировал зашифрованный пароль перед обновлением пользователя, вставлял после изменений, все так же.
Проблема, как понимаю, не в этом.

Каким образом можно посмотреть логи Spring Security.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950589/6810828 и в application.properties добавьте logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

Comment: @aleshka-batman , посмотрел лог, обновил топик. Как я понимаю, Spring не может найти пользователя в базе с таким именем. Но я не совсем понимаю, как такое может быть. Смотрю на пользователя с таким именем в базе.

Comment: User '2222' has no authorities. У юзера нет ролей в базе ?

Comment: @aleshka-batman , да, все верно, при обновлении пользователя, стираются данные в таблице с ролям.
Спасибо большое!)